# Vb.Net Value show zero for next loop ctype

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

After run the program I show value of `Power1` is zero, why?

Here codes;

```
Dim Guc1....Guc59 as decimal

Guc1=Val(TextBox5.Text)*Val(Textbox98.Text)
  . 
  .
  .
Guc59=Val(TextBox42.Text)*Val(Textbox12.Text)

For i = 1 To 59 Step 2


        Dim txt As TextBox = CType(TabControlPanel1.Controls("TextBoxX" & i), TextBox)
        Dim guc As Decimal = CType(("Guc".ToString & i), Decimal)

        Hız1 = Val(txt.Text) * RollinRadius * 3.14 * 3.6 / (Val(TextBox1.Text) * Val(TextBox33.Text) * 30)


        Power1 = guc * 3.14 / (30 * 1000) *2  *3)

        ListBox2.Items.Add(Power1)


    Next
```

Comment: Just as a side comment, there is no point to calling `"Guc".ToString`.  `"Guc"` is already a string so there is no point in calling `ToString()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Power1` is zero because `guc` will currently always be zero. You cannot access variables by their names like you're trying to do. `"Guc" & i` will just result in a normal string, which it cannot convert since `Guc` is not numerical. The only way to access variables dynamically by their name is to use [**Reflection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656692.aspx).

But the best way to do what you're trying to achieve is to use a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) or an [**Array**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx):

```
Dim Guc As Decimal = New Decimal(59 - 1) {} '59 - 1 = 59 items.

...

Dim gucx As Decimal = Guc(i - 1)

...

Power1 = gucx * 3.14 / (30 * 1000) * 2 * 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vincent, that worked. thanks for clarification.

Comment: @emraharslan : Glad to hear! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please mark my answer as accepted by pressing the check mark/tick on the left side of it.